# Output first part of array differently than second part

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
```

Basically i want my output for the first 5 rows to be inside `<div class = "firstcolumn">`

Once I have reached my five rows I want it to generate a second `<div class = "secondcolumn">` for the rest of the rows. Also the row outputs have to come inside the div tags. So I only generate one div that fills up with rows

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$cnt = 1;//Counter variable
foreach ($rows as $id => $row){
  if($cnt <= 5){
    $var = '<div class = "firstcolumn">';
  }
  else if($cnt > 5){
    $var = '<div class = "secondcolumn">'
  }
$cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with your style of coding, a loop counter will do the trick.

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php $colName = $i > 5 ? "secondcolumn" : "firstcolumn"; ?>

    <div class="<?php echo $colName; ?>">

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($rows as $id => $row) 
{
    if($count <= 5) 
    { 
        if($count==1){
    ?>
        <div class = "firstcolumn">
     <?php }?>
            <?php print $row; ?>


    <?php
    } 
    else 
    { 
        if($count==6){
        ?>
        <div class = "secondcolumn">
     <?php }?>

            <?php print $row; ?>
    <?php
    }
    if($count == 5){
    ?>
         </div>
    <?php
    }
    $count++;
}
if($count != 1 && $count!=6){
?>
     </div>
 <?php
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?